# AirPrint doesn't work with router that has DD-WRT installed

Tags: network, router, bonjour, airprint

Years ago, AirPrint worked in my house on my current printer. It's an HP Photosmart Premium and it absolutely does support AirPrint.

Then a year or two ago, I installed DD-WRT on my Linksys WRT160N router. I installed it so I could add a guest wireless network, but I probably shouldn't have, because the technical specifics of networking that I see everywhere on the DD-WRT site and forums are mostly over my head.

Soon thereafter, I noticed that AirPrint didn't work anymore. I searched and searched for things I could try to fix it, but what few answers I found either didn't work or assumed too high a level of networking knowledge.

I've had other faulty or missing behavior with some other Bonjour-related services like Screen Sharing, too, and I'm about to the point of just shelling out for an Airport Extreme. But before I do that, I ask you wonderful people: Is there anything I can try that doesn't require me to get a degree in networking to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, you can always use [the AirPrint Activator](http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/) (an app for your Mac) that allows you to use *any shared printer* via AirPrint. If you can get the printer to be available over your network, you’ll still be able to use AirPrint this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Wireless Access Point (WAP) configured as a router, and your AirPrint printer is connected to Ethernet, then your wireless AirPrint client and the printer are on different IP subnets. Link-local broadcast discovery protocols typically do not work through routers. That may be your problem, which can be fixed by configuring the WAP as a bridge.